# JS - Using multi-criteria cases in switch statement

Tags: javascript, switch-statement

I am using "[multi-criteria cases](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/switch#Methods_for_multi-criteria_case)" in my `switch` statement in order to handle the different values I am getting.

One of the things I am running into is this (dummy code from snippet below):

```
case '2':
  // Don't mind the inline styling, its' only for this example
  document.getElementById('output').lastChild.style.color = 'red';
case '2.5':
  document.getElementById('output').lastChild.style.color = 'white';
  document.getElementById('output').lastChild.style.backgroundColor = 'blue';
  break;
```

What I am attempting to do here is to set either `2` or `2.5`'s background color to be blue, but still set the text color uniquely based on the value.

Only that, like the code was meant to do, it overrides the text color of `2` with the text color of `2.5`.

---

#### There are two solutions I have worked out so far.

**The first is:**

```
case '2':
  document.getElementById('output').lastChild.style.color = 'red';
  document.getElementById('output').lastChild.style.backgroundColor = 'blue';
  break;
case '2.5':
  document.getElementById('output').lastChild.style.color = 'white';
  document.getElementById('output').lastChild.style.backgroundColor = 'blue';
  break;
```

**The second is:**

```
case '2':
  document.getElementById('output').lastChild.style.color = 'red';
case '2.5':
  if (e.target.textContent === '2.5') {
    document.getElementById('output').lastChild.style.color = 'white';
  }
  document.getElementById('output').lastChild.style.backgroundColor = 'blue';
  break;
```

The only *real* problem now is that I am a big fan of the "[DRY](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself)" theory. The above two solutions are, to some degree, "[WET](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself#DRY_vs_WET_solutions)."

Thus I am trying to figure out a better way to write this code, potentially something which looks like this:

```
case '2':
  document.getElementById('output').lastChild.style.color = 'red';
case '2.5':
  document.getElementById('output').lastChild.style.color = 'white';
case '2':  
case '2.5':
  document.getElementById('output').lastChild.style.backgroundColor = 'blue';
  break;
```

*(Even this is a bit "DRY")*

> **I understand that to some degree my code will be a bit "DRY" and I am willing to have that if necessary, I am just at the stage of lessening the code I do have for performance and want to see if I can cut the code down in any way possible.**

Here's a snippet with my dummy code in action:

```js
document.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
  if (e.target.nodeName === 'BUTTON') {
    document.getElementById('output').innerHTML += '<div>' + e.target.textContent + '</div>';
    switch(e.target.textContent) {
      case '1':
        // Don't mind the inline styling for this example pls
        document.getElementById('output').lastChild.style.backgroundColor = 'green';
        break;
      case '2':
        document.getElementById('output').lastChild.style.color = 'red';
      case '2.5':
        document.getElementById('output').lastChild.style.color = 'white';
        document.getElementById('output').lastChild.style.backgroundColor = 'blue';
        break;
      case '3':
        document.getElementById('output').lastChild.style.color = 'lime';
      case '3.5':
        if (e.target.textContent === '3.5') {
          document.getElementById('output').lastChild.style.color = 'cyan';
        }
        document.getElementById('output').lastChild.style.backgroundColor = 'red';
        break;
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<button id="b1">1</button>
<button id="b2">2</button>
<button id="b2-5">2.5</button>
<button id="b3">3</button>
<button id="b3-5">3.5</button>
<div id="output"></div>
```

### UPDATE

Going on, I figured there was another way to do this, which looks like this:

```
switch(e.target.textContent) {
  case '2':
  case '2.5':
    switch(e.target.textContent) {
      case '2':
        document.getElementById('output').lastChild.style.color = 'red';
        break;
      case '2.5':
        document.getElementById('output').lastChild.style.color = 'white';
        break;
    }
    document.getElementById('output').lastChild.style.backgroundColor = 'blue';
    break;
}
```

However, that basically is two of the same `switch` statements nested in one another.

*I am not trying to write all the wrong ways to do things (I know it looks like that), I am trying to figure out the right way to do it, maybe by testing all the wrong ways to do it.*

If anyone can help me with the right way to do this, that would be much appreciated.

Comment: In the case of this complexity I think the you would benefit highly with refactoring the conditional: https://sourcemaking.com/refactoring/simplifying-conditional-expressions

Answer (score 2):

This might be a slightly simplified solution. Is this what you're looking for?

```js
document.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
  if (e.target.nodeName === 'BUTTON') {
    var elem = document.getElementById('output');
    elem.innerHTML += '<div>' + e.target.textContent + '</div>';
    
    var txColor = '',
        bgColor = '',
        elemStyle = elem.lastChild.style;
    
    switch(e.target.textContent) {
      case '1':
 bgColor = 'green';
        break;
      case '2':
       txColor = 'red';
      case '2.5':
       txColor = 'white';
        bgColor = 'blue';
        break;
     default:
        bgColor = 'red';
        txColor = (e.target.textContent === '3.5') ? 'cyan':'lime';
    }
    
    elemStyle.color = txColor;    
    elemStyle.backgroundColor = bgColor;
    
  }
});
```

```html
<button id="b1">1</button>
<button id="b2">2</button>
<button id="b2-5">2.5</button>
<button id="b3">3</button>
<button id="b3-5">3.5</button>
<div id="output"></div>
```

Comment: looks good; like the ternary operator, but what if it's not my default statement? i.e. what If I wanted both 2 and 2.5 _and_ 3 and 3.5 operate the way I am asking?

Comment: yeah I see your point. It would be nice to make it a little more generalized. I'll put some more thought to it and see what I come up with.

Comment: Yeah I had an idea. It doesn't maintain use of the multi-criteria switch though. Since all of your keys are numbers, you can parse the number from the string key and then switch on the floor of each key. For each case, you can assign whatever bgcolor you want. Then for the text color, you can get the remainder of your keys and decided what to assign the text color based on that. You could use another switch statement, ternary operator, if statements, or even query from an object literal.

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like:

```
var config = {
  "1" : {
    "bgColor": "green"
  },
  "2" : {
    "bgColor": "red"
  },
  "2.5" : {
    "color": "white",
    "bgColor": "blue"
  },
  "3" : {
    "color": "lime"
  },
  "3.5" : {
    "color": "cyan",
    "bgColor": "red"
  }
};

document.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
  if (e.target.nodeName === 'BUTTON') {
    var output = document.getElementById('output');
    output.innerHTML += '<div>' + e.target.textContent + '</div>';
    for(var key in config) {
      if(e.target.textContent == key) {
        var obj = config[key];  
        if(obj['color']) {
          output.lastChild.style.color = obj['color'];
        }
        if(obj['bgColor']) {
          output.lastChild.style.backgroundColor = obj['bgColor'];
        }
      }
    }
  }
});
```

This way you can just edit the data layer (JSON) when you need to add more options. You also won't need to touch the click event.